# How to change Leaflet marker color on mouseover?

Tags: maps, leaflet, geojson, markers

I'm having a hard time figuring out why the Leaflet method `setstyle` will change the color of a polygon but not the color of my markers.

Polygon works fine:

[image: Polygon]

But the markers won't change colors:

[image: Markers]

I want to be able to mouseover a marker and changes its color.  It seemed like setStyle would do this.  But I keep getting `layer.setStyle is not a function`

I'm using Angular and Leaflet together to make the map (I'm using the angular-leaflet-directive).

Here's the mouseover part of the code:

```
$scope.$on("leafletDirectiveMap.geojsonMouseover", function (ev, leafletEvent) {
        pointMouseover(leafletEvent);
    });

    function pointMouseover(leafletEvent) {
        var layer = leafletEvent.target;
        layer.setStyle({
            weight: 2,
            color: '#666',
            fillColor: 'white'
        });
    }
```

When the marker get's moused over, it fires `pointMousever` which then tries to invoke setStyle on the LeafletEvent.target.  I've console.logged the LeafletEvent and there is indeed the Target part of it:

[image: Target]

Why would setStyle work for the polygon and not for the marker?  What's the way to change the marker's color?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out thanks to some documentation reading.

The polygon in leaflet responds to `setStyle` but the marker can be changed using `setIcon`

[Documentation for setIcon](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-seticon)